# How to install Oracle JDK 7 and Netbeans IDE in Linaro 13.01 ubuntu tty1?

Tags: netbeans, installation, java

I have a Processor A13(cpu: cortex-A8 ARM v7) of allwinner and my OS is Linaro 13.01 Ubuntu tty1.

So how do I install Oracle JDK7 and Netbeans IDE on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Oracle JDK for ARM processor and Hard Float OS Image is here.
[Oracle JDK for ARM Processor](https://blogs.oracle.com/hinkmond/entry/quickie_guide_getting_hard_float)

And download [Netbeans IDE 7.0.1](https://netbeans.org/downloads/7.0.1/) for Linux and install it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Ubuntu, there are several ways to install NetBeans. One way is to use Ubuntu's "Software Centre" which you can use just to search to NetBeans and it should install it including all dependencies.

You can also use your web browser in Ubuntu and head to www.netbeans.org and click "Download" at the top right, there you can choose your operating system and download the correct version of NetBeans.

Once downloaded you can run the NetBeans installer through terminal using: `sh ./<NetBeans file name here>`. And the installer will start.

**To install Open JDK:**

However, you may need to download and install the JDK first; which you can also do in terminal by typing: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

**To install Oracle JDK:**
This is taken from this link: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Remove open JDK from your system: `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*`

Create a new directory for the oracle JDK: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java`

[Download the Oracle Java JDK for linux by clicking here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Copy the Oracle Java binaries to the /usr/local/java directory: `cd /home/userName/Downloads`, `sudo -s cp -r jfk-7u13-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java`, `cd /usr/local/java`.

Extract the file: `sudo -s tar xvzf jdk-7u13-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Edit the system path file: `sudo nano /etc/profile`

Scroll to the bottom of the file and add this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_13
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Save the file and exit (Ctrl+X), then enter "y" for nano.

Let Ubuntu know where the Oracle Java JDK is:

```
LOCN="/usr/local/jdk7"

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "${LOCN}/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "${LOCN}/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "${LOCN}/bin/javaws" 1
```

Make sure Ubuntu knows to use this as the default JDK:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set java ${LOCN}/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac ${LOCN}/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws ${LOCN}/bin/javaws
```

Reload system path: `/etc/profile`, or just restart.

If you have trouble following my instructions then take a look at the link I posted above.

I would recommend using Open JDK instead though, as you can see; it's much easier to install.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply and help to me. but i want to install Oracle JDK not OpenJDK. This processore is like in TAB. So i tried .rpm jdk for 32 bit , but there was come errore at installing jdk or jre in this processore. This processore is different from the pc or laptop's processore.

Comment: @Jay Hi, I'll add how to install Oracle JDK at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not to spoil your fun, but the A13 is a very weak SOC for this task.

I wouldn't even try anything below dual Cortex A15 with 2GB RAM (The Samsung XE303).

Oracle now releases the standard JDK8 for ARM Linux hardfloat so it is possible to install it on Debian/Ubuntu fairly easily:

- Get JDK8 from Oracle's webpage (currently early access)
- Extract th tar.gz-d JDK8 ARM/LInux/hfloat into /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
- Use update-alternatives (first answer)
- Run "java -version" to check the results

..voila

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [Digital Ocean Docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps#downloading-oracle-java-jdk) how to manually install Oracle JDK on a headless ubuntu.

With a bit of Googling, I found following script to be useful.

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz
```